# How to copy an event from a public google calendar to the users with a url?

Tags: javascript, html, url, google-calendar-api

So I'm making a small tool that will help people generate cards for upcoming events.

link to repo - [Event Cards](https://github.com/Light1c3/EventCards)

I want to add a button that lets you add said event to your own calendar but am not sure how to go about doing that. I've tried `https://www.google.com/calendar/event?id=${items[i].id}` but that doesn't seem to work, only taking me to the calendar page. Everything I looked up online (my searching skill do leave a lot to improve) showed up to programmatically make new events but not how to copy an existing event from a public calendar. I hope I didn't miss something obvious.

This is the code I've tried so far:

```
var Root = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/';
var calendarID = '<My Calendar ID>';
var maxResults = 3;
var APIKey = '<My API Key>';
var currectDate = (new Date()).toISOString();
var EventsDiv = document.getElementById("EventCards");

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: Root + calendarID + "/events?maxResults=" + maxResults + "&timeMin=" + currectDate + "&singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime" + '&key=' + APIKey,
      method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(data) {
        var items = data.items;
        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

            console.log(items[i]);
            var startTime = getDateTime(items[i].start);
            var endTime = getDateTime(items[i].end);

            var card = `
                    <li class="card">
                        <div class="card--text">
                            <div class="text--container">
                                <div class="text--header">
                                    <a class="addEvent-btn" href="https://www.google.com/calendar/event?id=${items[i].id}"><i class="fas fa-calendar-plus"></i></a>
                                    <h2 class="text--title">` + items[i].summary + `</h2>
                                        `+ getEventLocation(items[i]) + `
                                        <p>` + getEventDate(startTime) + `</p>
                                        <p>` + getEventTime(startTime, items[i].start) + getEventEndTime(endTime, items[i].end) + `</p>
                                        ` + getEventDisc(items[i].description) + `
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <div id="map_canvas${i}" class="map_canvas"></div>
                    </li>`;
            EventsDiv.innerHTML += card;
        }
        for(var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++){
            if(data.items[i].location != null){
                mapInitilization(data.items[i].location, [i]);
                document.getElementById(`map_canvas${i}`).style.visibility='visible';
            }
        }
    });
});

function  getEventLocation(evntLocation) {
    if(evntLocation.location){
        return  `<p><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> ` + evntLocation.location + `</p>`
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}

function  getEventDisc(disc) {
    if(disc == null){
        return "";
    } else 
    return disc.substring(4);
}

function  getEventDate(date) {
    var length = (date.toUTCString().length - 13);
    return `<i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> ` + date.toUTCString().substring(0, length);
}

function getDateTime(event) {
    if(event.date != null) {
        return date = new Date(event.date);
    } else {
        return new Date(event.dateTime);
    }
}

function  getEventTime(time, event) {
    var length = (time.toLocaleTimeString().length);
    if(event.date != null) {
        console.log(event)
        return `<i class="far fa-clock"></i> All day`; 
    }
    return `<i class="far fa-clock"></i> ` + time.toLocaleTimeString().substring(0, length - 6) + time.toLocaleTimeString().substring(length - 3, length);
}

function  getEventEndTime(time, event) {
    var length = (time.toLocaleTimeString().length);
    if(event.date != null) {
        console.log(event)
        return ``; 
    }
    return ` - ` + time.toLocaleTimeString().substring(0, length - 6) + time.toLocaleTimeString().substring(length - 3, length);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Also, any suggestions for the little project I'm working on would be awesome :D

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out :D

If you look at the calendar API response, you should see an option for htmlLink. That link will directly open up your Google Calendar and bring up a dialog box with the option to add that event to your calendar.

So it'll look like this:`<a class="addEvent-btn" href="${items[i].htmlLink}"><i class="fas fa-calendar-plus"></i></a>`

Hope this helps someone!